# Boost C++, how to check if someone is connected to serial port on the other side

Tags: c++, boost, serial-port

I am looking for solution on how to determine if someone is connected to serial port on the other side. So, I have the client that opens port and just waits for the bytes incomming. I want him to have other serial connection and check if soneone is connected , then send him bytes from first serial. But I really need to know that someone is indeed connected. Is there some way to check it on air?

Comment: You probably need to check the DCD (Carrier Detect) and/or DSR (Data Set Ready) pins on the serial port. Does boost have a way to check the status on those?